Right usage of 'large' ("The windows in the front room are 10 m × 12 m large")
Is it correct to say 'this is  x cm large'?
For example, is it O.K to say

The windows in the front room are 10 m × 12 m large.


We could consider

The windows in the front room are 12m wide by (or and) 10m high.


The windows in the front room are 12m(W) by (or and) 10m(H).


The windows in the front room are 12m in width by (or and) 10m in height.

We can read more about dimension descriptions and names of various parts here.
